# What isthe use of Generic handler In asp.net.?

Tags: asp.net

I am new in Asp.net. But am familiar with jsp .I am searching for how to add a controller for an asp page. Ad I want to know what is this Generic Handler.

Comment: Can you clarify by what you mean by "controller" and "generic handler"? Are you referring to the use of Generics?

Answer (score 0):

Please say clearly what do you mean by "controller".
Generic Handlers(.ashx) are basically HTTP Handlers that can process requests to exactly one url. They are good substitute for .aspx file in some cases like writing out the contents of files stored in the server for download etc.